# Return a Javascript function to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)
>   [Passing a Javascript string to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116222/passing-a-javascript-string-to-php)

I have this javascript code inside a PHP file:

```
<script>
function(){
var mail="comitalia@faac.it";
for(var i=0; i<json_load.length; i++){
    if(json_load[i].custom.tipologo == "FAAC FILIALI"){
        mail=json_load[i].custom.email;
    }
}
return mail;
}
</script>
```

I need to return the "mail" variable to a PHP variable. How can I do that??

Comment: Post/get is the standard way of trasnmitting data over http

Comment: so many duplicate questions, it's hard to know which to link to. You need to learn about Ajax, and more generally how prorgams in a client/server environment (like a browser/web server) work.

Answer (score 2):

Either submit the mail variable via `submit()` in jquery, or use `AJAX`.

Manuals: [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: window.location.href,
  dataType: "json",
  data: mail,      
  success: function(response) { 
      //do something with response     
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the basics, you can not pass java-script values to the php variable. Because PHP is rendered at the server-side and java-script is rendered at the client side. [Read this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).

What you can do is, You can pass the data to the server using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: path/to/the/php/file.php,
  mail: mail,      
  success: function(response) { 
   //if you return something from the server-side you get it here     
  }
});
```